# Restore OS X desktop icon size

Tags: macos, desktop, icons

Somehow I changed the size of the icons at my desktop.

How can I restore them to their original size?

This is how they look now:

[image]

Comment: You mean you don't like icons that take up half your desktop? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change them back in the Finder menu. Click anywhere on your desktop and type Command+J this should bring the menu up. In versions earlier than Snow Leopard I believe the default size is 48x48. I think SL may be 64x64

Comment: I realize later that I can do the two fingers pinching Doh!...

Answer (score 0):

the GUI way

Or go into the system prefs. and click on the blue guy in a blue circle," the disability icon", this lets you change the icon size in you're blind and also lets you enable a screen flash/